# N Queens - Java

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I was solving the N queens question myself and went with a different approach thaat was mentioned in the solution as well as online.

My code is working for inputs up to 4 but starts to print every case (even those are wrong) for any value after 4. I've checked it a lot of times but I'm unable to find any bug in the code.

PFA the code and see if you can find the bug. 
Thanks!

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= scn.nextInt();
        int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
        printNQueens(arr,"",0);
        System.out.println();


    }

    public static void printNQueens(int[][] chess, String qsf, int row) {
        if(row==chess.length)
        {
            qsf = qsf + ".";
            System.out.println(qsf);
            return;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<chess[0].length;j++)
        {
            if(chess[row][j]==0)
            {
                int x=row,y=j;
                while(x<chess.length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                }
                x = row;
                while(x<chess.length && y>=0)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                    y--;
                }
                x = row;
                y = j;
                 while(x<chess.length && y<chess[0].length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }
                printNQueens(chess,qsf + row + "-" + j + ", ",row+1);
                x = row;
                y = j;
                 while(x<chess.length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                }
                x = row;
                while(x<chess.length && y>=0)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                    y--;
                }
                x = row;
                y = j;
                 while(x<chess.length && y<chess[0].length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you are potentially setting chess fields to `0` after the recursive call that were `1` at the beginning of the function. The simplest fix would be to copy the array for the recursive call and set additional `1`s there while keeping the original array unchanged.

Comment: @flyx it worked. I was using the clone function which somehow was not working. So, I iterated through and copied each element. I wonder though using this approach will significantly increase the memory usage and complexity, right?

Comment: Yes, memory usage will increase, complexity may (needs calculation). To reduce memory usage and be able to properly backtrack, instead of memorizing the board, mark each occupied row, column and diagonal. Since each can only be occupied once, you can reset them after the recursive call. Calculating whether a field is free will then take three comparisons instead of one, which is a constant and thus not worsens complexity.

Comment: @flyx I found a way to do it with arraylists. Please check the answer I posted and let me know if it's better than copying the whole array everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
```

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= scn.nextInt();
    int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
    printNQueens(arr,"",0);
    System.out.println();


}

public static void printNQueens(int[][] chess, String qsf, int row) {
    if(row==chess.length)
    {
        qsf = qsf + ".";
        System.out.println(qsf);
        return;
    }
        for(int j=0;j<chess[0].length;j++)
        {
            if(chess[row][j]==0)
            {
                chess[row][j] = 1;
                ArrayList<Integer> ro = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Integer> co = new ArrayList<>();
                int x=row+1,y=j;
                while(x<chess.length)
                {
                    if(chess[x][y]==1)
                    {
                        ro.add(x);
                        co.add(y);
                    }
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                }
                x = row+1;
                y = j - 1;
                while(x<chess.length && y>=0)
                {
                    if(chess[x][y]==1)
                    {
                        ro.add(x);
                        co.add(y);
                    }
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                    y--;
                }
                x = row+1;
                y = j+1;
                 while(x<chess.length && y<chess[0].length)
                {
                    if(chess[x][y]==1)
                    {
                        ro.add(x);
                        co.add(y);
                    }
                    chess[x][y] = 1;
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }
                printNQueens(chess,qsf + row + "-" + j + ", ",row+1);
                x = row;
                y = j;
                 while(x<chess.length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                }
                x = row;
                while(x<chess.length && y>=0)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                    y--;
                }
                x = row;
                y = j;
                 while(x<chess.length && y<chess[0].length)
                {
                    chess[x][y] = 0;
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                while(x<ro.size() && y<co.size())
                {
                    chess[ro.get(x)][co.get(y)] = 1;
                    x++;
                    y++;
                }

            }
        }


}
```

}